# What card game is this?

Tags: identify-this-game, playing-cards

Dealer deals 3 cards to each player first, they’re not supposed to look at those. Then another three that you can look at but don’t touch go above them when the deck runs out of cards.

So the general gameplay is to have a higher card, you have three in your playing deck (not the ones you haven’t seen or the ones after card deck is empty) say one is a 10, that erases the pile and it’s set aside or maybe that’s 2.

I just remember the 2’s and 10’s were good cards to have if you didn’t have a higher number. also if four of a kind is placed that clears the deck as well. you can also have an even number and not have to take the whole deck.

I’m not really good at explaining it because I played when I was in a psych ward so my memory is a little fuzzy but I remember it being the funnest card game I ever played.

Answer (score 4):

You are describing [Shithead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shithead_(card_game)) or one of its many variants.

from the wikipedia page.

> From a standard, shuffled deck of cards, each player is dealt 9 cards
> in total: 3 face-down cards in a row (blind cards), 3 face-up cards on
> top of the blind cards, and 3 hand cards

also

> Twos and tens are wildcards, and can be played on any card. Any card
> can be played to follow a two. When a ten is played, the discard pile
> is immediately "burned" (removed from play) and the same player takes
> another turn, playing any card or set to begin a new discard pile.

In the version I played years ago 7's were considered transparent and could be played on anything as if invisible.